# Google App Engine PHP suddenly stopped running apps locally

Tags: php, python, google-app-engine

Google App Engine PHP suddenly stopped running my app locally today. I have tried re installing Python(2.7.8) and GAE SDK (1.9.10) with no luck.

App Engine Log:

```
2014-09-12 19:01:29 Running command: "['C:\\Python27\\python.exe', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\google_appengine\\dev_appserver.py', '--skip_sdk_update_check=yes', '--port=8080', '--admin_port=8000', 'C:\\raven3mil']"
INFO     2014-09-12 19:01:32,002 devappserver2.py:725] Skipping SDK update check.
WARNING  2014-09-12 19:01:32,010 api_server.py:383] Could not initialize images API; you are likely missing the Python "PIL" module.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\dev_appserver.py", line 82, in <module>
    _run_file(__file__, globals())
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\dev_appserver.py", line 78, in _run_file
    execfile(_PATHS.script_file(script_name), globals_)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\devappserver2\devappserver2.py", line 970, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\devappserver2\devappserver2.py", line 963, in main
    dev_server.start(options)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\devappserver2\devappserver2.py", line 768, in start
    request_data, storage_path, options, configuration)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\devappserver2\devappserver2.py", line 867, in _create_api_server
    default_gcs_bucket_name=options.default_gcs_bucket_name)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\devappserver2\api_server.py", line 416, in setup_stubs
    simple_search_stub.SearchServiceStub(index_file=search_index_path))
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\api\search\simple_search_stub.py", line 653, in __init__
    self.Read()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\api\search\simple_search_stub.py", line 1117, in Read
    read_indexes = self._ReadFromFile()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\api\search\simple_search_stub.py", line 1091, in _ReadFromFile
    version, indexes = pickle.load(open(self.__index_file, 'rb'))
EOFError
2014-09-12 19:01:32 (Process exited with code 1)
```

Any ideas as to what's going on? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Have you tried to install the PIL module? 'WARNING  2014-09-12 19:01:32,010 api_server.py:383] Could not initialize images API; you are likely missing the Python "PIL" module.'

Comment: Yes; still doesn't work. To my knowledge it's irrelevant anyway: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-appengine-go/gDImZqkPOp8

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try running your application with the option `--clear_search_indexes=yes`

In the launcher, select the app, then edit->application settings.. and add `--clear_search_indexes=yes` to the extra command line flags field.

Or if you use the console you can do something like: `dev_appserver.py -A your_app_id --clear_search_indexes=yes`

Hope it helps.